# como fazer um login dividido em duas partes?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Oque eu quero fazer é tipo um sistema de login de banco com duas senhas de acesso, a primeira parte ja fiz, então eu queria levar o login a `parte 2` onde pede a `senha 2` e o `nome do usuario`.

Caso ele acesse coretamente a `parte 1` ele vai para a parte dois com os respectivos dados, mas se ele não tenha feito o login da `parte 1` da erro.

Comment: Podes colocar o código que já fizeste? senão é dificil saber o que te está a faltar...

Answer (score 0):

Estou bem enferrujado com PHP, então tentar exemplificar com um codigo generico aqui...

Acho que o jeito mais interessante seria trabalhando com session

```
    if(classeDeLogin.validaUsuarioParte1('usuario','senha')
    {
         $_SESSION['login1'] = true;
         //Redireciona para a pagina de login 2
    }
```

Nessa pagina você poderia fazer o seguinte

```
    //Verifica se o login parte 1 foi realizado
    if($_SESSION['login1'] == true)
    {
    if(classeDeLogin.validaUsuarioParte2('usuario','senha')
       {
          //Aqui não lembro exatamente o comando, mas a idéia é atribuir null a variável de sessão login1
          $_SESSION['login1'] = null;
          $_SESSION['userLogged'] = true;
          //Redireciona para sua pagina principal

       }
    }
    else
    {
        //Redireciona para pagina de login parte 1
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia  ,

Após validar o 1 login ,você joga o nome de login dele em uma sessão e redireciona para a tela login2.

Na tela login 2  , no campo login você exibe o nome que esta na sessão e pede para informar a senha . Ao informar a senha você faria uma validação normal igual na etapa 1.Se a verificação na etapa 2 der certo , você redireciona o usuairio para index , senão  , você pode mandar ele de volta para a pagina de login 1 ou para a pagina de login 2 mesmo .